# mat-select selected text in center

Tags: mat-select

I used the code .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
height: 40px !important;
} which is used to reduce the height of the mat-form-field, after reducing the height, selected text is displayed in the center vertically, please guide me to do that.